# UNION types integer and text cannot be matched.in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, union-all

```
select product_name ,0 price1,0 price2,0 price3,
(CASE when sum(price)>100 then 1 else 0 end) as price4,0 price5
 from sales_1
 group by product_name,price
 union 
 select product_name ,0 price1,0 price2,0 price3, 0 price4,
(CASE when sum(price)<100 then 'yes' else 'no' end) as price5
 from sales_1
 group by product_name,price
```

I want values which are less then 100 to turn into 'no' and others to 'yes' but it is throwing an error which is'UNION types integer and text cannot be matched' .i have tried different type of casting to solve it but it didn't. and i am doing it in postgresql

[image: 1]

Comment: Cast that column to TEXT since 'yes' and 'no' can't be integers.

Comment: Can you formulate your aim? Generally use a column (`price`)  in a `group by` **and** in `sum` is not a meaninfull approach.

Comment: In the first half of the union use `'0' price5`

Comment: @MarmiteBomber actually i want a specific date data from the price column so that was the reason why i was doing this. and i have posted my answer here which give my my required result.But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code which got me to my required result:

```
SELECT product_name,
       0 price1, 0 price2, 0 price3,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(price)>100 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END) AS price4,
       '' price5 
FROM sales_1
GROUP BY product_name,price
 
UNION ALL

SELECT product_name, 
       0 price1, 0 price2, 0 price3, '' price4,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(price)<100 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END) AS price5
FROM sales_1
GROUP BY product_name, price
```

And this is the result I got from upper query:

[image]